# Flutter setState not updating child element

Tags: flutter, widget

I have an InkWell which uses `onTap` to perform some actions. When the button is tapped, I like an indicator to be shown (in case the action is long-running). However, the `setState` in the InkWell does not trigger its children to be re-rendered. The code is as follows:

```
class PrimaryButtonState extends State<PrimaryButton> {

bool _apiCall;

Widget getWidget() {
  if(_apiCall) {
    return new CircularProgressIndicator();
  } else {
    return Text(
      widget.label,
    );
  }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final List<Color> colors = //omitted

  return InkWell(
    child: Container(
      decoration: // omitted
      child: getWidget(), // not updated when _apiCall changes !!!!!
    ),
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        _apiCall = true;
      });
      widget.onTab(context);
      setState(() {
        _apiCall = false;
      });
    }
  );
}
}
```

How can I solve this that `getWidget` returns the correct widget dependent on `_apiCall`?

---

EDIT:

The `widget.onTap` contains the following:

```
void performLogin(BuildContext context) {
final String userName = _userName.text.trim();
final String password = _password.text.trim();

UserService.get().loginUser(userName, password).then((val) {
  Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainLayout()));
}).catchError((e) {
  // omitted
});
```

}

it is passed with the widget:

```
class PrimaryButton extends StatefulWidget {

  final bool isPrimary;
  final String label;
  final Function(BuildContext context) onTab;

  PrimaryButton(this.label, this.isPrimary, this.onTab);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PrimaryButtonState();

}
```

My main concern is, that the given `onTap` method should not know it is "bound" to a UI widget and therefore should not `setState`. Also, as this is a general button implementation I like it to be interchangeable (therefore, `onTap` is not hardcoded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is because you are calling `setState()` twice in your `onTap()` function. Since `onTap()` is not an async function it will set `_apiCall = true` in the first setState, then immediately run `widget.onTab(context)` and then immediately perform the second setState() to set `_apiCall = false` so you never see the loading widget.

To fix this you will need to make your onTab function an async function and await for a value in your onTap function for your InkWell:

```
onTap: () async {
      setState(() {
        _apiCall = true;
      });
      await widget.onTab(context);
      setState(() {
        _apiCall = false;
      });
    }
```

This will also let you use the results of your onTab function to show errors or other functionality if needed.

If you are unsure how to use async functions and futures [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-guide-to-using-futures-in-flutter-for-beginners-ebeddfbfb967) is a good guide on it that goes over this exact kind of use case.

Comment: Ok, but as I can't (nor want) to call `setState` in the passed `widget.onTap` method, how can I solve this?

Comment: Can you update your post with the widget.onTab method so I can see what it does, and also let us know where it comes from?

Comment: If you want to only call setState inside the button widget, you will need to make your performLogin() function an async function and return a future, the best would probably be a bool, so that your onTap function can use it. Then you would return true from the function if it is successful or false if not in your onError section, and then be able to call setState after the future completes in your button's onTap.

Comment: I could do this. Can you edit your answer (with an example for others looking for this) so I can accept it.

Comment: Updated the answer with an example for making the button async, and a guide for making the passed onTab function work async.